# Tikz trees align equations

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

How can I align the equations in this diagram?
I have tried using the align environment but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{hktkrkrkrrrkrkrkrkrk}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
        \matrix (tree) [%
        matrix of nodes,
        minimum size=.2cm,
        column sep=1cm,
        row sep=.2cm,
        ]
        {
            &   & \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{uu} &= \$19.8375\\[-4pt]
                C_{uu} &= \$3.83750\\
            \end{aligned}\) \\
            & \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{u} &= \$17.25\\[-4pt]
                C_{u} &= \$1.876093565\\
                \Delta &= .88985507250
            \end{aligned}\) &   \\
            \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{0} &= \$15\\
                C_{0} &= \$.9171927207\\
                \Delta &= .50029161740
            \end{aligned}\)
            &   & \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{ud} &= \$15.525\\[-4pt]
                C_{ud} &= \$0\\
            \end{aligned}\) \\
            & \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{d} &= \$13.5\\[-4pt]
                C_{d} &= \$0\\
                \Delta &= 0
            \end{aligned}\) &   \\
            &   & \(
            \begin{aligned}
                S_{dd} &= \$12.15\\[-4pt]
                C_{dd} &= \$0\\
            \end{aligned}\) \\
        };
        \draw[-] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[-] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {};
        \draw[-] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[-] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {};
        \draw[-] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[-] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please I am kindly asking for your help on how to fix the issue.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you looking for such diagram?

[image]

**Edit:**
You need to replace ampersands in matrix with for example `\&` that they can be distinguished from ampersands in nodes. Beside this in your particular case, for perfectly aligned equations in matrix columns, you need to anchor nodes to the west too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{hktkrkrkrrrkrkrkrkrk}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (tree) [matrix of math nodes,
                nodes = {anchor=west},
                column sep=1cm,
                row sep=.2cm,
                ampersand replacement=\&
                ]
{
    \&   \& \begin{aligned}
            S_{uu} & = \$ 19.8375  \\
            C_{uu} & = \$  3.83750 \\
          \end{aligned}                     \\
    \& \begin{aligned}
        S_{u}  & = \$17.25\\ 
        C_{u}  & = \$1.876093565\\
        \Delta & = .88985507250 \\
            \end{aligned}   \&              \\
\begin{aligned}
    S_{0} &= \$15\\
    C_{0} &= \$.9171927207\\
    \Delta &= .50029161740
\end{aligned}   \& \& \begin{aligned}
                        S_{ud} &= \$15.525\\%[-4pt]
                        C_{ud} &= \$0\\
                      \end{aligned}     \\
    \& \begin{aligned}
        S_{d} &= \$13.5\\[-4pt]
        C_{d} &= \$0\\
        \Delta &= 0
     \end{aligned}  \&                  \\
    \&  \& \begin{aligned}
                    S_{dd} &= \$12.15\\[-4pt]
                    C_{dd} &= \$0\\
               \end{aligned}                \\
        };
\draw   (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2)
        (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2)
        (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3)
        (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3)
        (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3)
        (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the output to be such that all the equations in each column are perfectly aligned like what you did for column 1 and column 3. Can you help by adjusting the code?

Comment: @it, this is not clear from your question (at least too me).

Comment: can you please help by making all equations perfectly aligned like what you did in column 3. Please I need help

Comment: @itc, they can not be perfectly aligned since they are independently
 placed in matrix nodes. In edited answer you can find quite good approximation of what you like to have.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko.

Comment: @itc, you should maje yourself more familiar with this sie policy. Instead of saying `thank you`  you should  vote answer (by stroke up-triangle at top left side of answer). As far I see, so far you also not accept any of received answers on your 10 question. By this you tell us, that no one of received answers is useful for you (about this I deeply doubt). Please, be so kind and check received answers again and accept (by stroke check mark at top left side of answer) those of them which solve your problem on the best way.

Comment: You mean the up arrow and the tick?